# Different Main Navigation per category

Tags: query, navigation

I have a client who has the categories listed in the right-hand sidebar. He came to me today requesting a different "navigation" in the header for each category.

So basically, if you click on Category 1, the navigation changes to a set of pages (that he has set) and so on.

Is this even possible? I already have the built in menu feature activated, but I am really at a loss for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set this in your theme using conditionals. Create a separate menu for each category using the WordPress menu feature (Appearances > Menus). Then in your theme, where you want the menu to display, determine which menu to display using the is_category('category-slug') and/or in_category('category-slug') conditionals and the wp_nav_menu function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

For instance:

```
<?php
if(is_category('first-category') || in_category('first-category)) { 
     wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'First Category Nav' )); 
} else {
     wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Default Nav' ));
}
?>
```

That said, from a user-experience standpoint I'd recommend against switching out the main menu on a section-by-section basis. That will be very confusing for visitors. I'd recommend an additional category-specific menu instead, with consistent main navigation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_nav-menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) allows you to call menus in different ways, by slug for example.

Just create multiple menu and add conditional logic so one of alternate menus is called if on category page.