# How to get or know the slug of home.php

Tags: menus, slug, homepage

I found this code from [Different Main Navigation per category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19169/different-main-navigation-per-category):

```
<?php
if(is_category('first-category') || in_category('first-category')) { 
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'First Category Nav' )); 
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Default Nav' ));
}
?>
```

And want to re-use this to display different main nav in my `home.php` and the rest of the page.

I came up with this:

```
<?php
if(is_page('???') || in_page('???')) { 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
       'menu' => 'Main Nav Menu',
       'container' => ''
    )); 
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu' => 'Nav Menu',
        'container' => ''
    ));
}
?>
```

But I don't know where to find this home.php slug,
I tried 'home' as slug but i turned out an error page:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function in_page() in D:\xampp\htdocs\wp-xxx\wp-content\themes\BLANK-Theme\header.php on line 62
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_home()` for the home page (the list of newest blog posts), and `is_front_page()` for the front page (can be a static page too).

```
if( is_home() ) 
{ 
    wp_nav_menu( 
        array(
            'menu'      => 'Main Nav Menu',
            'container' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, can you show me the code?
e.g. below, how am I gonna put it?
    <?php
    if(is_home() || in_page('???')) { ... }

Comment: @LizzaFaith See my update.

Comment: thanks, it worked, I can have different main menu in different page